# Mathematica .Net/Link in an Asp.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wolfram-mathematica

I am using the Mathematica [.Net/Link platform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/CallingMathematicaFromNET.html) to create a web service to format and calculate math problems. However I am unable to get it working.

I create it using this code:

```
_Log.IpDebug("Starting the Kernel Link");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_MathLinkArguments))
   _InternelKernel = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
else
   _InternelKernel = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink(_MathLinkArguments);
_Log.IpDebug("Kernel Link Started");
_InternelKernel.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();
```

The value of `_MathLinkArguments` is `-linkmode launch -linkname \"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\7.0\\Math.exe\"`.

This piece of code is called from the `Application_Start` method of the global.asax.cs file.

When it gets to the `WaitAndDiscardAnswer()` call it gives the server error:

```
Error code: 11. Connected MathLink program has closed the link, but there might still be data underway.
```

Note: The SampleCode given with the .NET/Link package (both a console app and a WinForms app) works.

Edit:
I copied the console app sample code given with Mathematica into an asp.net page and it gave me the same error the first load and then on subsequent loads it gave me:

```
Error code: 1. MathLink connection was lost.
```

Edit2:
I forgot to mention that when I have procmon and task manager open while running my app, I can tell that Math.exe starts but it immediately exits, which makes those error code make complete sense...but doesn't explain why that happened.

Comment: It is not clear from your question if it works with no _MathLinkArguments specified. Did you check that _InternelKernel variable is not null ? I am sure you known that linkname is just a string, does not have to be this complicated. A unique identifier is OK. Does the following work in your Mathematica `kernel = LinkLaunch[
  "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\7.0\\MathKernel.exe" <> 
   " -linkmode launch -linkname uniqueIdentifier123"]; Print[
 LinkRead[kernel]]; LinkClose[kernel]`

Comment: it doesn't work with no _MathLinkArguments either, but the error is that it just hangs and never loads the page.  Also, when I run that piece of code in Mathematica I get `InputNamePacket[In[1]:= ]`

Comment: did you try to create a stand-alone CS program with the equivalent of the code posted ? Does it work ?

Comment: I didn't create one, but it comes with 2 bits of sample code, and one of them accepts an argument for the args, and I used the arguments specified here to make it, and it worked.  And then I tried making a new page that had copy/pasting the code from the console app code and that gave me the same error (the first time) then `Error code: 1. MathLink connection was lost.` whenever I refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow the .Net/Link to work in Asp.net (at least in IIS 7.5) you need to enable the property `loadUserProfile` on the app pool for the web site.

I am not entirely sure why this is the case, but from what I found while trying to debug this, there are some things that are gotten from the user's profile. I know for a fact that the default location of the kernel is, which explains why I couldn't use it with no arguments, and so I can only assume that other things are needed as well and without the profile it couldn't determine that.

But whatever the reason is this is required, it is, or at least it is a fix if you are getting similar problems like this in your own application.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in a .Net WinForm application.

```
mathKernel = new MathKernel();
mathKernel.Compute("<< XYZ`XYZGraphs`");
```

The error occurred on loading the package straight after instantiating the MathKernel.

To resolve it you can wait a couple of seconds and then instantiating the MathKernel works fine. During this state where there might still be data underway the following conditions are both false:

```
if (!MathKernel.IsConnected)
{
    MathKernel.Connect();
}

if (MathKernel.IsComputing)
{
    MathKernel.Abort();
}
```

**Edit:**

I've recieved the error again and this time was able to determine the problem.

Using a command line open the MathKernel.exe and view the error message:

[image]